# Reducing the run time of a loop and increasing its efficiency

Tags: python, performance, loops, processing-efficiency

I have a loop that takes a large number of words, breaks each word into letters and attaches them to a big list.

I then check for the letter that occurs the most, and if it doesn't already appear in a string, I'll store it in a list that has two spaces:

`list[0]` = letter that occurs the most

`list[1]` = how many times it occurs

This loop is super inefficient. It works, but it takes around 25-30 seconds to return a value. Before that it would keep going and wouldn't return any values.

How can I increase the efficiency of the code I've written?

```
def choose_letter(words, pattern):
    list_of_letters = []
    first_letter = []  # first spot is the letter, second is how many times it appears
    second_letter =[]  # first spot is letter, second how many times it appears
    max_appearances = ["letter", 0]
    for i in range(len(words)):  # splits up every word into letters
        list_of_letters.append(list(words[i]))
    list_of_letters = sum(list_of_letters, [])   # concatenates the lists within the list
    first_letter = list_of_letters.count(0)
    for j in list_of_letters:
        second_letter = list_of_letters.count(j)
        if second_letter >= max_appearances[1] and j not in pattern:
            max_appearances[0] = j
            max_appearances[1] = second_letter
        else:
            list_of_letters.remove(j)
    return max_appearances[0]
```

Comment: This may be a better candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: and when you move over to codereview, they're gonna ask to see the output of the profiler you ran against this code.

Comment: Looks like a job for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Whatever you do I believe you will gain a lot from using dictionaries for storing your counts and not lists. So `dict`, `defaultdict` or the above mentioned `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it go faster is to choose a better data structure. Here is an example using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def choose_letter(words, pattern):
    pattern = set(pattern)
    letters = (letter
               for word in words
               for letter in word
               if letter not in pattern)
    letters = Counter(letters)
    return letters.most_common(1)[0][0]


mywords = 'a man a plan a canal panama'.split()
vowels = 'aeiou'
assert choose_letter(mywords, vowels) == 'n'
```

Here is one using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def choose_letter(words, pattern):
    pattern = set(pattern)
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for word in words:
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in pattern:
                counts[letter] += 1
    return max(counts, key=counts.get)

mywords = 'a man a plan a canal panama'.split()
vowels = 'aeiou'
assert choose_letter(mywords, vowels) == 'n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of looping & manipulating lists that you don't need.  Every time you do a `count` or a `not in`, you're forcing your program to loop through a list/string to find what you're looking for.  Removing all those items from your list is also pretty expensive. A much more elegant solution would be to loop through your list of words/letters just once and then use a dictionary to count occurrences of each letter. From there, you have a dictionary with character/count pairs & you can just get keys/values from there, sort the list & look at the first two values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

def choose_letter(words, pattern=""):
    count_dict = defaultdict(int) # all unknown values default to 0
    for c in chain(*words):
        count_dict[c] += 1
    # you could replace this "not in" with something more efficient
    filtered = [(char, count) for (char,count) in count_dict.items() if char not in pattern] 
    filtered.sort(lambda a,b: -cmp(a[0], b[0]))
    print filtered
    return filtered[0][0]
```

If you don't want to dig into argument unpacking, itertools & defaultdicts, you could just say:

```
count_dict = {}
for word in words:
    for char in word:
        count_dict[char] = count_dict.get(char, 0) + 1
```

...if you don't want to try digging into argument unpacking yet.